# Define common Pydantic fields, use subsets of them in models

Tags: python, design-patterns, types, fastapi, pydantic

### Setup

I have a long list of variables to be used in email templates.

###### Example

```py
cust_name: str  
bill_address: str  
ship_address: str  
ref_num: int
# ...list continues
```

Overlapping combinations of these appear in the templates, which I've modeled using Pydantic.

###### Example

```py
class TemplateA(BaseModel):
    cust_name: str
    bill_address: str

class TemplateB(BaseModel):
    cust_name: str
    ref_num: int

class TemplateC(BaseModel):
    bill_address: str 
    ship_address: str

# ...and so on
```

### Question

I'd like to know if there's a recommended way to centrally define my `variable: type` combos so I'm not repeating myself, and if I change a variable name or a type, those changes are reflected everywhere.

Pydantic model inheritance isn't working for me because so many combinations of fields are mixed and matched across template models. I'm open to the idea of changing my approach entirely if there's a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My Answer

You can use `pydantic.create_model`.

- https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/concepts/models/#dynamic-model-creation
- https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/errors/usage_errors/#create-model-field-definitions

### My Example

```py
from pydantic import Field, create_model

# [field definitions]

cust_name = str, Field(default='ccc')
bill_address = str, Field(default='bbb')
ship_address = str, Field()
ref_num = int, Field()


# [models]

TemplateA = create_model(
    'TemplateA',
    cust_name=cust_name,
    bill_address=bill_address,
)
TemplateB = create_model(
    'TemplateB',
    cust_name=cust_name,
    ref_num=ref_num,
)
TemplateC = create_model(
    'TemplateC',
    bill_address=bill_address,
    ship_address=ship_address,
)


# [constructions]

print(TemplateA().model_dump())
# > {'cust_name': 'ccc', 'bill_address': 'bbb'}

print(TemplateB(ref_num=1).model_dump())
# > {'cust_name': 'ccc', 'ref_num': 1}

print(TemplateC(ship_address='ship_address').model_dump())
# > {'bill_address': 'bbb', 'ship_address': 'ship_address'}
```

Comment: This indeed allows me to avoid complicated inheritance - thank you. I expect the trade-off is I lose IDE/Linting support since the models are built at run-time. Not a deal-breaker but curious if there are steps you'd recommend to address that concern?

Comment: What's the issue in your IDE? BTW, I use Visual Studio Code

Comment: Linting wasn't the right term. To clarify: when I hover TemplateA in VS Code I'd like to see info about the class and its constructor arguments and types - normally the language server (Pylance) can figure this out, but here it's unable to do so. Maybe it's the nature of the beast with dynamically created models, and docstrings are the next-best solution. Do you know any other way to hint the class signature to Pylance?

Answer (score 1):

Generating a subset type (i.e. generating your models from one big type) is not possible in Python's type system (in e.g. Typescript you could do this with `Pick`).

I guess you technically **could** define one Pydantic model per field, and then build your actual models using multiple inheritance:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class _CustNameField(BaseModel):
    cust_name: str

class _BillAddressField(BaseModel):
    bill_address: str

class _SkipAddressField(BaseModel):
    ship_address: str

class _RefNumField(BaseModel): 
    ref_num: int

###################################

class TemplateA(_CustNameField, _BillAddressField):
    pass

class TemplateB(_CustNameField, _RefNumField):
    pass

class TemplateC(_BillAddressField, _SkipAddressField):
    pass
```

Not sure I would recommend it, it seems like a pain to work with when you have many fields, but it would accomplish what you're after.